# Как остановить счетчик setInterval без применения Date?

Tags: javascript

```
var b;
var a=0;
function timm(){
 a=a+1;
  console.log(a);
if(a>=0 && a<=5){b=setInterval(timm,1000);
}
else{clearInterval(b)};
}
timm()
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var b;
var a = 0;

function timm() {
  if (a == 0)
    b = setInterval(timm, 1000);
  console.log(++a);
  if (a > 5)
    clearInterval(b);
}
timm();
```

Comment: Требуется что бы счетчик включался и выключался внутри функции